# ZF2 and reverse proxy: identify logged in users

Tags: session, zend-framework2, reverse-proxy

Currently, ZF2 uses the PHPSESSID cookie to store all session data, like when a user is logged in.

I would like to use a reverse proxy and need therefore to identify logged in users by a non-generic cookie, so they may pass the proxy.

Is this possible?